# socket.broadcast.to().emit() vs socket.to().emit() vs io.to().emit()

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

What is the main difference among:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {

  // socket.broadcast.to(socketId).emit();
  // socket.to(socketId).emit();
  // io.to(socketId).emit();

});
```

All of them works as same, but what is the difference ???

Comment: Related; possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342681/whats-the-difference-between-io-sockets-emit-and-broadcast and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57458399/socket-broadcast-to-emit-vs-socket-to-emit

Comment: @CodyGray, it is only about room but mine is about socket_id and it is two way and mine three way